# Array slicing in inside operator in system verilog constraints

Tags: arrays, constraints, system-verilog

```
///* Example 1.1 */
program automatic test;
    class pkt;
        rand bit [3:0] array[12];
        rand bit [3:0] value;
        int count;
        function new(int cnt);
            count = cnt;
            this.randomize();
        endfunction: new

        constraint c {
              value inside {array[3:count]};
        }
    endclass: pkt

    initial begin
        pkt p;

        repeat(10)
        begin
          p = new(6);
          $display("==================");
          $display("array = %0p and value = %0d", p.array, p.value);
          $display("==================");
        end
    end
endprogram
```

I want `value` to have a value inside `array` with index ranging from `3` to `count`.

But getting error,

> this.array[3:this.count]"
>     The expression 'this.array[3:this.count]' contains an unpacked array slice 
>     that is not yet supported on the right-hand side of the inside operator.
>     Please remove the array slice from the constraint expression, or replace it 
>     with entire array.

Is there any way to acheive this ? without extra variables is more fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the array reduction iteration constraint.

```
module test;
    class pkt;
        rand bit [3:0] array[12];
        rand bit [3:0] value;
        int count;
        function new(int cnt);
            count = cnt;
            this.randomize();
        endfunction: new

        constraint c {
          array.or() with (item.index inside {[3:count]} && item == value);
        }
    endclass: pkt

    initial begin
        pkt p;

        repeat(10)
        begin
          p = new(6);
          $display("==================");
          $display("array = %0p and value = %0h", p.array, p.value);
          $display("==================");
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

All slicing operators in system verilog require **constant** width of the slicing. In your example you are trying to use a non-constant lsb expression `count`. This will not work. It should either be a constant like `[3:1]` or you need to use the `+:`/`-:` syntax, e.g. `array[count +: 3]` meaning, start slicing from index `count` and take **3** elements from the array. **The width must be constant**.

I think, in your case you can use a parameterized class and pass `count` as a class parameter. Something like the following:

```
class pkt#(int count = 1);
  logic [3:0]a[3:0];
  function print;
     $display ("++> %d", $bits(a[3:count]));
  endfunction
endclass

initial begin
  pkt #(2) p = new;
  p.print;
end
```

Comment: you can as long as it is an integer type and occupies a contiguous space.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think how to do this with a simple constraint. Here is a solution:

You do need an extra variable (not so fine):

```
rand int index;
```

And, you need to modify your constraint:

```
constraint c {
  index inside {[3:count]}; value == array[index];
}
```

so that a random value of `index` is chosen between 3 and `count` and then value is chosen to be the corresponding element of `array`.

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3ata

```
program automatic test;
    class pkt;
        rand bit [3:0] array[12];
        rand int index;
        rand bit [3:0] value;
        int count;
        function new(int cnt);
            count = cnt;
            this.randomize();
        endfunction: new

        constraint c {
          index inside {[3:count]}; value == array[index];
        }
    endclass: pkt

    initial begin
        pkt p;

        repeat(10)
        begin
          p = new(6);
          $display("==================");
          $display("array = %0p and value = %0h", p.array, p.value);
          $display("==================");
        end
    end
endprogram
```

Comment: This is not legal according to the LRM: *Individual array elements can be constrained, in which case the index expression may include iterative constraint loop variables, constants, and state variables.* But some tools allow simple cases like this.

Comment: @dave_59 Sorry - I don't follow. This English seems to suggest one "may" constrain an individual array element. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this sentence slipped through the IEEE grammar police. The sentence should read *individual array elements may be constrained, in which case the index expression shall include an expression containing only iterative constraint loop variables, constants, and state variables*